# Google Indoor Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-mobile, indoor-positioning-system

How do I get access to the Google Indoor Maps on my Android app? I currently have a GPS app using Google Maps APIs but it doesn't show the indoor maps for Switzerland.

I can access the indoor maps for Switzerland (Sihlcity, Zurich Airport) using the official Google Maps app on Android so ideally it should work in my personal Android app as well.

Does it work using the same Google Maps APIs or is there a separate logic for indoor maps?

Many thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 6):

The "MapView" component that comes with the "Google APIs" SDK plugin for Android has just been updated to "v2", it looks like:

http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2012/12/better-maps-in-your-android-apps.html

The docs are here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

And the MapFragment (now vector based and 3D) that replaces the old MapView includes indoor maps.

Comment: The integration of maps doesn't enable all the Indoor functionality. For eg: After integrating the maps v2, the indoor map comes up on proper zoom level but the store details on the floor level is not enabled, whereas when you open the same location Indoor Map on the Google Maps App it displays store details. Any idea to fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

As long as I can see, it should be the same API used for outdoor/traditional navigation. In the Google Maps API documentation nothing makes me think that a different API is used for indoor navigation.

Maybe you are using a different version of the Google Maps API on the "official" Android device (Google Maps 6.0/API 3.0, latest official version) and on your GPS "Customized" device (an older version of Google Maps not supporting indoor maps and navigation), hence the different behavior.